Should I have to hold the handle down on new American Standard toilets?
I was told by my plumber that I had to hold the handle down to get the toilet to flush properly. The plumber showed me how I needed to hold the handle down to flush, but I'm wondering if this is correct, or if he didn't want to or didn't know how to install it properly.
Everything I am reading says it is a problem with the length of the chain, that it's not normal. He took all the packaging with him, so I don't know if there were any directions included that would say if that was normal to save water or if I have been duped.

Toilets generally do not come with instruction manuals.  When needed you push the handle to flush. If that does not happen to your satisfaction, it should have been discussed with the installer at the time of installation.  Perhaps call the company back and tell them of the dissatisfaction with the product and ask for a technician to come out to make adjustments.

Thank you, but Im still not getting the answer I am looking for.  I tend to believe what people tell me, and he said "with this toilet, you have to hold the handle down to flush" Is that because of the type of toilet, or because of improper installation?

We have no way of knowing, Provide the model number of the toilet.

Even better, a clear photo showing the chain and flapper.

Toilets generally do not come with instruction manuals.     Never thought I'd see the day.

Some toilets have a "hold-down-until-flushed" system, to save water. We have this type now: a button on the top of the tank. A quick tap on the button starts a small flush, sufficient to clear the bowl of liquid-only waste. Hold the button down for 2 to 3 seconds for a full solid waste removal flush.
I have not seen side-handle-flush toilets with partial flush capability. But I have seen side-handle-flush toilets that won't do a full flush, because the chain or handle are not adjusted correctly.
If the rubber flapper at the bottom of old-school toilet tanks is not pulled up enough, the flapper gets rammed shut by the flowing tank water, and the flush gets cut off. Perhaps the chain is too long, or the rod attached to the side handle is mis-installed and strikes the tank lid, preventing full swing of the handle.
If your new toilet has the old-school flapper, then check the chain and handle rod. The flapper should pull up fairly to vertical or more during the flush and stay up through most of the flush.
If your new toilet does not have the old-school flapper, then it may very well be a "hold-down-until-flushed" system for water saving.
